# Linux: Create files and direcotires but not delete them

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a process that create directories and files inside a working directory, ex:

```
/workingdir/file1
/workingdir/file2
/workingdir/dir1/file1
/workingdir/dir1/dir2/file1
/workingdir/dir1/file2
```

I need to avoid deletion/overwrites of created folders/files for that user, but allow subsequent folders/subfolders/files creation.
I try permissions, gid, acl with no luck.

What is the correct way to do that ? (i can use a cron job if needed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to achieve something by setting extended attributes with [chattr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr).

Use `chattr +a` on your directories. This will allow them to be added to but will stop them from having files removed.

Use `chattr +i`  to make your files immutable - they cannot be changed once this is set.

> A file with the ‘a’ attribute set can only be open in append  mode  for
>          writing.    Only   the   superuser   or   a   process   possessing  the
>          CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.
>
> A file with the ‘i’ attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be  deleted
>          or  renamed,  no  link  can  be created to this file and no data can be
>          written to the file.  Only the superuser or a  process  possessing  the
>          CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

Comment: The perfect combination. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with standard POSIX unix file permissions.

The best you can accomplish is a directory where users will be able to delete any files they own, but not those of other users.

```
chmod 1775 /directory
```

**UPDATE:** You can have more fine gained control with SELinux or Apparmor but from that approach you have to give permissions to processes on files.

**UPDATE:** You have the option of using the system append-only flag for separate files. Not on all filesystems: *chattr +a filename*